# What is does mean in the stated link when the author uses "ordinary signs"

Tags: terminology

[image]

=================

In this particular image what is the author referring to when he uses ordinary signs. Is he referring to previous stated definition of signs consisting of a pair words (with a signifier and the signified) ?

If not, then what would be the difference between an ordinary sign and a language sign ?

============== Context ================

http://linguistics.ucla.edu/people/Kracht/courses/ling20-fall07/ling-intro.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The author hasn't been very careful about "ordinary". He just means "non-linguistic".

A sign, as the chapter says, is a pair of things: a **signifier** (what you sense by sight, hearing, etc.) and something **signified**.

A linguistic sign is one where the signifier is part of a language, usually a spoken or written word.

By "ordinary sign", then, the author means one where the signifier is *not* part of language. The author gives the example of a clock. Say a clock face has the long hand pointing to 0 degrees (north) and the short hand pointing to 90 degrees (east).

[image: clock]

This is a sign with a straightforward relationship between signifier and signified. The arrangement of the hands is the signifier and the signified is that it's 3 o'clock.

Signs like this, as the author says, are much more limited than language. The clock has a couple of possible meanings: perhaps it's 3 a.m. and not 3 p.m., and perhaps it's that time in Seoul rather than Los Angeles. But it can't do anything but tell you the time. Whereas (it is argued) language is a system of signs allowing you to express essentially any meaning.